# shared product image is not displaying on fb

Tags: facebook, opencart

I am trying to share my product on facebook through share widget. Its getting shared but product image is not getting displayed. 
I have been trying from past 2 days to solve this. But it is not working. 
(I am using OC 1.5.6.4)
here is the webpage i am trying to share the product from : http://teesfor5.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=68

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the below tag in your html.

```html
  <meta property="og:image" content="YOUR_IMAGE_LINK_HERE"/>
```

Also you can get more information on your page's meta tags by opening this link  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and putting in your page's link. It will let you know what other meta data is missing from your page.

Comment: _“You need to include an `<og:image>` tag in your html”_ – not, it has to be a `meta` element with `property="og:image"`.